# Exporting bold sentences in Microsoft Excel

Tags: html, excel, text, fonts

I want to export bolded parts of sentences in Excel, but I don't know exactly where to start. For example: "Purple, **lovely chair** that **creates a comfortable zone** in your living room!". And I want these words in the next column, so I can't use finder because he works only on bolded whole cells. I need that to write then program to add before and after every bolded sentence HTML code strong and /strong. Do you have any ideas :)? I can only say that I've tried VBA but I'm not quite good at it so it has not worked. Many thanks to all!

Comment: Partial formatting is done on the character level.  You will have to check each character in each cell of interest. Range.Find won't work, as you note.

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas You don't have to be that sarcastic, I didn't expected from you making a whole code, I just needed a hint, just like L. Scott Johnson did, and thank you for that. Now I'm thinking about making a GetBold function in VBA with pWorkRng as Range

Comment: sorry for this. deleted the comment :)

Comment: I wrote something like this, but now i don't really know how to make <strong>S</strong> before every bolded sentence and how to swap it, anyone have any ideas? 
Function GetBold(R As Range)
Dim i As Long, S As String
For i = l To R.Characters.Count
    If R.Characters(i, l).Font.Bold = True Then S = S & Mid(R.Value, i, l)
Next i
If S = "" Then
    GetBold = ""
Else
    GetBold = S
End If
End Function

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29917943/4717755) uses the same approach for checking individual character formats, FYI.